# Systemd service depending on another from a different server

Tags: systemd, rhel, services

We're dealing with a (vendor-provided) distributed application, that runs on multiple servers. The servers aren't "equal" -- the main one has to be up and running before the secondary ones can be started.

How can I express this dependency in the `secondary.service` file? I'd like the following:

1. At startup, the secondary services on all of the secondary servers wait for the primary service *on the primary server* to be started. I know, this can be achieved with a custom `ExecStartPre` -- but, in my opinion, it truly belongs in the `After` (or `Require`) clause of the secondary service's `[Unit]` section.
   The `systemctl` utility has the `--host` option -- is there a similar syntax for referencing remote services inside a `.service` file?
2. If/when the primary service is shut down, the secondaries shall all go down too.
3. Once the primary service is back up, the secondaries shall all start up too.
4. The previous two can be based on an explicit notification from the primary service, with a periodic check for its health -- to catch the situations, when the primary service is brought down *abruptly*.

Can any of the above be done using systemd's own mechanisms, or do I need to implement a separate health-monitor service of my own on each secondary server?

We're using RHEL7, where systemd is of a fairly old version 219... Also, if it matters, all of the mentioned services run under `systemd --user` -- not as "system".